# How to call several TCP Listeners on the main scricpt

Tags: python, python-3.x, tcplistener

I acquired several car trackers (GPS and other I/O data) and I need to build a TCP listener.
My goal is to have a couple of the trackers listening to port x and some of port y (same server).

I want to start two scripts (TCP Listener x and TCP Listener y) on the 'main script'.

I understand that the bind only is possible with one port.

This is a piece of my code (TCP Listener):

```
class TCPServer:
def __init__(self, port):
    self.port = port
    self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    self.sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
    self.sock.bind(('', self.port))

def tcp_server(self):
    self.sock.listen()
    while True:
        conn, addr = self.sock.accept()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
        thread.start()
        print(f"[ACTIVE CONNECTIONS] {threading.activeCount() - 1}")

def communicator(self, conn, imei):
    accept_con_mes = '\x01'
    conn.send(accept_con_mes.encode('utf-8'))
    print("handshake complete\n")
```

...

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
port = xxxx
data = TCPServer(port)
data.tcp_server()
```

The main script looks like this:

```
import listener_x
import listener_y

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data_x = listener_x.TCPServer(port=xxxx)
    data_x.tcp_server()

    data_y  = listener_y.TCPServer(port=yyyy)
    data_y.tcp_server()
```

One symptom is that if I left the main script like this, I can receive the data of the Listener x, and not the listener y.

If I switch the listeners on the main script, listener y first then listener x, I receive the data of the listener y and not of the listener x.

I will appreciate any help.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your initial assumption is incorrect. When creating a TCP server socket you specify the port that the server listens on. Then when a client connects you accept the connection and this yields a new socket. You can have multiple clients connect to your server port and each has its own socket. You then typically use select to wait for activity on any of the set of client sockets and respond appropriately. A quick google search yields a [reasonable example](https://realpython.com/python-sockets/#echo-server) that starts with a simple socket echo server and moves on to support multiple simultaneous clients

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I do exactly that on my code, my clients it's the different trackers, and yes, I need to accept the connection.
If it's possible, I want to run the 2 TCP listeners on the same script and see both on a single terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Possible with threading.
Example:

```
import threading
import client

class TCPListener:
def __init__(self):
    self.providers_test = {5000: 'https://examplea.com', 6004: 'https://exampleb.com'}
    def app(self):
    keys = []
    values = []
    items = self.providers_test.items()
    for item in items:
        keys.append(item[0]), values.append(item[1])

    print("keys: ", str(keys))
    print("values: ", str(values))

    data = client.TCPServer(port=keys[0])
    data.tcp_server()

def initiate_app(self):
    thread_app = threading.Thread(target=self.app())
    thread_app.start()
if __name__ == '__main__':
TCPListener().initiate_app()
```